# How to set the content type to json

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to upload my scraping spiders to my S3 bucket, which works well. The issue here is, when I click on the link on each spider, it will start downloading the json file. I want it to open the json file, in a new tap. As I understood it, it has to know the correct content type. And since its a json file, the content type should be 'application/json'. But why can't I find this opportunity?

[image]

Comment: You should be able to just type anything you want in that field.

Comment: Had no clue, it works! Thanks!!!